# amCharts Serial Chart unable to display data after enabling data parsing "parseDates": true

Tags: javascript, json, spring, amcharts

I am using spring as webservice and JSON response after hitting is following:

```
[ {
  "date": "2016-04-17",
  "open": 1085.0,
  "high": 1092.2,
  "low": 1072.0,
  "close": 1088.3,
  "volume": 54100,
  "value": 1088.3
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-14",
  "open": 1081.25,
  "high": 1081.25,
  "low": 1081.25,
  "close": 1081.25,
  "volume": 0,
  "value": 1081.25
} ]
```

I am trying to create chart for stock analysis. When I set `"parseDates": false` graph showing data. But of course, date is not parsed. When I set `parseDates` to `true` it stops showing data.

Here's my JavaScript Code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "left"
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "proCandlesticks": true,
    "balloonText": "Open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>Low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>High:<b>[[high]]</b><br>Close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>",
    "closeField": "close",
    "fillColors": "#7f8da9",
    "highField": "high",
    "lineColor": "#7f8da9",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
    "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
    "openField": "open",
    "title": "Price:",
    "type": "candlestick",
    "valueField": "close"
  } ],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "scrollbarHeight": 30
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": false
  },
  "dataProvider": resp,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "position": "top-right"
  }
} );

chart.addListener( "rendered", zoomChart );
zoomChart();


function zoomChart() {
  chart.zoomToIndexes( chart.dataProvider.length - 50, chart.dataProvider.length - 1 );
}
```

Comment: whats ur `data` like? or show `resp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data points on date-based chart must be ordered in ascending order. Oldest first, newest last. Looking at your data sample, it seems to be that they are in descending order.

To fix that simply call `reverse()` on your `resp` array:

```
resp.reverse();
```

Working demo:

```js
/**
 * Source data
 */
var resp = [ {
  "date": "2016-04-17",
  "open": 1085.0,
  "high": 1092.2,
  "low": 1072.0,
  "close": 1088.3,
  "volume": 54100,
  "value": 1088.3
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-14",
  "open": 1081.25,
  "high": 1081.25,
  "low": 1081.25,
  "close": 1081.25,
  "volume": 0,
  "value": 1081.25
} ];

/**
 * Reverse array
 */
resp.reverse();

/**
 * Create chart
 */
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "left"
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "proCandlesticks": true,
    "balloonText": "Open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>Low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>High:<b>[[high]]</b><br>Close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>",
    "closeField": "close",
    "fillColors": "#7f8da9",
    "highField": "high",
    "lineColor": "#7f8da9",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
    "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
    "openField": "open",
    "title": "Price:",
    "type": "candlestick",
    "valueField": "close"
  } ],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "scrollbarHeight": 30
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true
  },
  "dataProvider": resp,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "position": "top-right"
  }
} );
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , you saved me .. Please keep going like this :) , god bless you